# In Magento2 how to create custom less file for particular store?

Tags: magento2

In Magento2, how to create custom.less file for a particular store ? 
i created custom themes like theme1, theme2 and theme3 in magento2 
and also i created custom.less file only in theme but when i hit the command to compile this less file but is generated in all themes folders 
i am only create this custom.less file in theme

these steps i follow to compile

step 1  : i am created **custom.less** file
step 2 : i am run these command to generate from custom.less to csutom.css
         - **php bin/magento setup:static:content:deploy -f**
         - **php bin/magento cache:clean**
conculsion : but this custom.css file generated in all themes.

i have created multistore websites. i have created custom.less file in first store theme but after executed all the commands  css file is generated in all stores.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "less file"? How does it related to all the yellow boxes you've posted?

Comment: actually i create the structure like that theme is stores --- i want to aply less file in pirticular store "custom.less" when this compiled then "custom.css" is generated

Comment: Can you clarify that and edit the question accordingly? What is a "particular store"?

Comment: hello @NicoHaase please review png file i am updated

Comment: Please do not put relevant information into images, explain it in words. Still, I don't know what you want to ask us using a list of folders

Comment: i want to create a custom.less file for theme1 , i done this before but the issue is this custom.less file when compiled that time it is created in all themes , but actually i want this in theme 1 only i guess you got it ?

Comment: So, then you should at first edit your question to contain all that information, secondly explain how you compile your less file. After all, this looks more like a problem of your compiler than a problem of Magento, so using appropriate tags will help to find the experts for your problem

Answer (score 0):

**Working with LESS in magento 2 specific store**

**step1** : Go in your custom theme  > web > css > source > there is _soucrces.less
file if it is not there then copy this file from magento-blank-theme.

**step2** : After copied that file type code for import your file eg. <@import 'CustomCss.less';> here CustomCss.less is your file name

step3: now create one less file in following path  ( web > css > source > CustomCss.less ) yourfile name name starts should be underscore ( CustomCss )

**step4** : Now declare your custom variables in _variables.less file , you can find this file in following path (web > css > source )
file if it is not there then copy this file from magento-blank-theme. ( optional step ) or you can declare variables in same LESS file

**step5** : After creating this files write css rules and also use variables which you are created.

step5: in your theme default_head_block.xml

add your css file in head section

result: code which in the less files it is added in customCss.css